# How secure are the GPG/PGP keyservers?

Tags: encryption, web-application, cryptography, attacks

Importing a GPG key with a KeyID or fingerprint seems to rely on keyservers. Doesn't this invite man-in-the-middle attacks, in which someone would alter the keys to allow them to decrypt the data? What measures are in place to prevent this, and what alternatives are there to using a keyserver to and a key to a keyring with only a KeyID or fingerprint?

Side question: are the private keys uploaded along with the public keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, there are multiple ways

1. You can use Digital Certificates. But weakness is web browser doesn't give any warning message if certificate provider is changed it only checks for expiry date. you can have more info from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_certificate#Weaknesses)
2. Use of [Cryptome](http://cryptome.org/2013/07/mining-pgp-keyservers.htm) which offers you better security but might not resolve man in middle attack  perfectly.
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869036/how-to-defend-data-from-mitm-attacks-over-https) might be the solution which will prevent you from man-in-middle attack.

Answer (score 8):

Importing a GPG key with a KeyID *seems* to rely on key servers -- but, in reality, it does not. A key server is an *untrusted* storage area. When you import a key, you shall not use it before having duly verified that the key is genuine, i.e. is really the public key of whom you believe owns it. That the key came from some key server proves *nothing*; neither the transmission protocol, nor the key server storage itself, offers any protection against attacks. And, in any case, you don't know who owns the key server and thus you will certainly not trust them.

In order to verify a GPG key, you can:

1. Check its *fingerprint*, which is really a hash value. This is for the cases where you met the key owner and he gave you a copy of his key fingerprint. Fingerprints are short enough to be printed on business cards or spelled out over a phone call (I have done both). Hash functions are *second-preimage resistant*, and that's good enough.
2. If the fingerprint is not available, build *chains*: keys signed by other people, whose public key you can verify (possibly recursively). This exercises the [Web of trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust), which is what passes as a PKI in the PGP world.